# Python confusion with return value in try-except-finally

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch, finally

Here is a piece of my code:

```
def main():
    num = 0
    try:
        raise Exception('This is the error message.')
    except Exception:
        num += 1
        return num
    finally:
        num += 1

a = main()
print(a)
```

The returning value is `1` instead of `2`, this does not make a lot of sense for me.

I thought it would return 2 since finally should execute before returning the value.

Can someone help me to understand this?

Comment: @KlausD. This is not true. [When a return, break or continue statement is executed in the try suite of a try…finally statement, the finally clause is also executed ‘on the way out.’](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#finally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into the difference between an identifier and a value. `num += 1` is creating a new `int` object and assigning the `num` identifier to point to it. It does not change the `int` object the identifier is already pointing to. (For small values the `int` objects are cached but that's an implementation detail)

You can see the difference with an operation that does mutate the object in the below code:

```
def y():
    l = []
    try:
        raise Exception
    except Exception:
        print("except")
        l.append(1)
        return l
    finally:
        print("finally")
        l.append(2)

print(y())
# except
# finally
# [1, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks, never realized that the objects are different in except and finally.

Comment: @Fed_Dragon It's nothing special about finally. if you did `l = [n]`, and then `n += 1`, then value in the list will not change even though the value `n` points to does.

Answer (score 1):

The `finally` is executed (this is clearly defined in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#finally)), but as you return an **immutable object**, the modification is unseen as your returned name is now part of a different scope.

This would work as you expect with a mutable object, for instance a list:

```
def main():
    lst = [0]
    try:
        raise Exception('This is the error message.')
    except Exception:
        lst[0] += 1
        return lst
    finally:
        lst[0] += 1
a = main()
print(a)
```

Output: `[2]`

Answer (score 0):

The `finally` block *does* execute before returning the value, but the return value has already been computed.

`return num` evaluates `num`, getting `1`, then the `finally` block starts. The `finally` block increments `num`, but the return value has already been evaluated, so it doesn't matter. At the end, the `1` computed earlier is returned.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are returning in except block
Using return word will end code execution in this function.
To avoid it you could write like this:

```
def main():
 num = 0
 try:
    raise Exception('This is the error message.')
 except Exception:
    num += 1
 finally:
    num += 1
 return num

a = main()
print(a)
```